# Not receiving APNs when out of app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase as my backend and I am using **Cloud Messaging** for **Push Notifications**, but my app receives notifications only when the app is open (and Push Notifications do not display when the app is open). I have checked out the Firebase docs and other code examples and I cannot find anything specifically I am missing, and I am receiving the correct output when the app is open. The issue is that no notification appears when outside of the app and no notification banner shows up at all, only xcode console output. This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        FIRApp.configure() //this is the changed version.

        if let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token(){
        print("Target Token ID: \(token)")
        }

        let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
        print("TOKEN:\(token)")



    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //FIRApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_,_ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)


        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quit4rRs the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     //*   FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
     //*   print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        connectToFcm()

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        print("QQWQW")
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }
        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error!)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }



}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)

    }



}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {

        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
        print("QQQQQ")
    }
}
```

This is the output when a message is received:

```
%@ [AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = myMSG;
    e = 1;
}, AnyHashable("from"): 492525072004, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.myApp]
QQQQQ
```

Again, the output **only** displays when inside the app, which defeats the point of Push Notifications. There also is no banner being displayed at all which I presume is because Push Notifications for the app do not display when inside of the app.

Comment: Can you post the paylod you are sending?

Comment: I am sending a message from the Firebase Console. It is a simple notification with only a piece of text in it. I am sending it to an individual device, which only receives the message when the application is in the foreground.

Comment: Have you tried setting the priority to high?

Comment: yes @Chris I am sending the notifications from the firebase console